# Unable to remove values from result table in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures

I have This Stored Procedure which works up until certain point

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_RunSearchPostFilter`(vResultTable VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM groupuser u, groups g WHERE u.GroupID=g.GroupID AND g.GroupName REGEXP 'design_group' AND u.UserID=@vUserID) THEN

SET @prep=CONCAT("

    DELETE r FROM ", vResultTable, " r
    JOIN file f ON r.FileID = f.FileID
    JOIN path p ON f.PathID = p.PathID
    JOIN keyword1 k1 ON f.FileID = k1.FileID
    AND k1.Field136 = 'Prep'
    OR (
     *code to hide files within directories with k1.Field136="Prep"*
    )

;");

PREPARE sprep FROM @prep;
EXECUTE sprep;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE sprep;

END IF;
END
```

Basically I have a temporary table passed to the stored procedure as parameter IN (called `vResultTable`) that is something like this:
vResultTable(ID);

Then I have the following 3 tables which are involved for getting data across tables:
File( FileID, FileName, PathID, Dir );
Path (PathID, Path);
keyword1 (FileID, Field136);

The result table (vResultTable) is basically nothing more then a list of File IDs. Some of those file IDs have a column (Field136) in the keyword1 table with value "Prep". Those IDs might be files or directories. If they are files, the problem is not there, as I find the exact match and I am able to remove those IDs from the result table. The problem i am facing is when those IDs are directories, as I need to remove all files (not having a value in Field136 column) being inside one of those folders having value "Prep" in the keyword1.Field136.
I have tried creating a temporary table, store all IDs of files/directories having the "Prep" value and then try to loop, but it does not work.
The SP above works when it comes to files having value "Prep", but if there are IDs of files that ha not direct value of "Prep" but they are contained in a directory having that value, I cannot make it to remove it.

EX.
vResultTable (IDs)
5   <--- "image1.jpg"   Has keyword1.Field136 = "Prep" so removed with no problem
64 <--- "anchor.png"  Has no value, but it's full path is "/Xinet_Volume/Images/Lot1/Folder1/anchor.png"  The directory "Lot1" has keyword1.Field136 = "Prep" therefore this file should be removed from the result table
2   <--- "house.pdf"    No value and not within ant directories with value, so it is visible
4   <--- "005.pdf"        Same as ID=64.

I have tried to solve this problem for days now and I am drained. I have exhausted all my options, and I need someone merciful to help me out with this.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Messy that, even with a recursive structure. Can we assume Lot1 as a directory name is unique, i.e it appears no where else in any other path? e.g. /Xinet_Volume/Images/Others/Lot1/Folder2/wobbly.gif

Comment: Unfortunately not. Lot1 might be on another folder structure like /Xinet_Volume/Documents/Countries/Lot1/flags/uk.png

Comment: You need to change your path table then I think. Perhaps make it self referencing. So Path is A, A/B, A/B/C etc then you can tell Lot1 in one path from another. That way you can come up with a query which finds all paths that exist in the file table with (or without) the flag value. Still messy though.